# Multiple header in recyclerview android

Tags: android, layout, header, android-recyclerview

I have created a recyclerview for displaying data which is fetching from the server. I had used only single layout for displaying the data.

Now my requirement is like when I upload images or videos, then the uploading status should be displayed on top of the data which is displaying from the server. i-e on 0th position of recyclerview. I can add any number of images or videos.

after image or video successfully upload i also want to remove that row from recyclerview. I thought of doing using getItemViewType(). In this using two layout. I don't know this method is correct or not. I am not getting any solution to this,

Please.....

any help...

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve that using the library [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter).

You should first create a section class:

```
class MySection extends StatelessSection {

    String title;
    List<String> list;

    public MySection(String title, List<String> list) {
        // call constructor with layout resources for this Section header, footer and items 
        super(R.layout.section_header, R.layout.section_footer,  R.layout.section_item);

        this.title = title;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return list.size(); // number of items of this section
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(list.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        return new SimpleHeaderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        MyHeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (MyHeaderViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your header view here
        headerHolder.tvItem.setText(title);
    }
}
```

Then you set up the RecyclerView with your Sections:

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

MySection uploadsSection = new MySection("Uploads", uploadList);
MySection downloadsSection = new MySection("Downloads", downloadList);

// Add your Sections
sectionAdapter.addSection(uploadsSection);
sectionAdapter.addSection(downloadsSection);

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

This way you manage the items from your upload and download lists separately by removing them from uploadList/downloadList then notifying the changes to the adapter. The upload items will always be displayed at the top of the RecyclerView because they are in the first section added to the adapter.

If you have different layouts for uploads and downloads you can create a different Section class for each.

Answer (score 0):

Make two viewTypes like:

```
private static final int REGULAR_HOLDER = 1;
private static final int LOADING_HOLDER = 2;
```

Override getItemViewType and return LOADING_HOLDER for position 0, and REGULAR for all others. Also have state if you are loading or not. If you are not loading anything you will return REGULAR_HOLDER for all rows (positions).

Then in onCreate check if you have REGULAR or LOADING viewType, and create proper Holder. Important: make your Adapter implement `RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>` not your custom implementation of ViewHolder.

onBind executes next. There you will have to check if your viewHolder object you get is `instance of RegularViewHolder` or `instance of LoadingViewHolder`, like:

```
if (holder instance of RegularViewHolder) {
     holder.doStuff();
} else if (holder instance of LoadingViewHolder) {
     holder.showLoading();
}
```

Now, before this you should made two layouts. One is for your regular rows, and other is for row that will show loading. Make two classes that implement ViewHolder, in example above i called them `RegularViewHolder` and `LoadingViewHolder`.

EDIT: few things to keep in mind. I told you to keep a loading state (loading or not loading), so if you want to remove LOADING row, you could make that change and call `notifyDataSetChanged();`. Now, `getItemViewType` should return all REGULAR rows if you did it right.

Also you should keep in mind that if you want to show 10 rows of your data. Your `getItemCount()` should return 11 (10 + loading row) if there is loading happening. Also, in that case your data rows start from second row (position 1).

Comment: What if I am uploading more than 1 media files. i-e for eg: suppose there are 10 headers(LoadingViewHolder), then how should I remove the row which has finished uploading.

Comment: If you understand how Adapter works:  getItemCount -> getItemViewType -> onCreateViewHolder -> onBindViewHolder, it would be possible. But it is quite specific and I can't explain it here in comment. You can do it on same principle as my example above, but my suggestion is to find and read some articles about multiple holder view types to understand how adapter works.